# Replace text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to replace text on a site using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function() {
            $(document.body).find('*').each(function() {
                var tmp = $(this).children().remove();
                var text = $(this).text();
                text = text.replace(/Vorname/g, "Firstname");
                $(this).text(text);
                $(this).append(tmp);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

HTML (snippet) is like this (generated by SharePoint):

```
<td style="padding:4px;">
<div>
    <label for="ctl00_IWS_WH_CPH_Content_ContactUsControl1_firstName">
        <span><font color='red'>*</font> Vorname (erforderlich):</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

The above jQuery code is not being executed...
Reference to jQuery has been placed in the master page.

Any clue why this is not working?

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: So your starting with the body, removing all children of all elements, and then you'd like to replace the text where exactly?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.element').text("sometext");
```

i think this is not right

```
var text = $(this).text();
                text = text.replace(/Vorname/g, "Firstname");
```

you should use:

```
var text = $(this).text();
    text.replace("Vorname", "Firstname");
```

then you should document better your question, i don't understand your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found you are using two doc ready functions you have to use only one:

```
Either : $(document).ready(function () {

or :     $(function() {
```

and see if this works.

Thanks

Comment: Right. "$(document).ready(function () { " and "$(function() {" is the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf3xQ/30/)

check the jsfiddle link for the working code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$(document.body).find('*').each(function() {
                var tmp = $(this).children().remove();
                var text = $(this).text();
                text = text.replace(/Vorname/g, "Firstname");
                $(this).text(text);
                $(this).append(tmp);
            });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are stripping off some elements style. If you want to keep layout you better have to use html not text, but it really depends of what you are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('body').find('*').each(function() {                
       var html= $(this).html().replace(/Vorname/g, "Firstname");
        $(this).html(html);
    });
 });
```